# How can I format date displayed on wxDatepickerctrl on wxPython?

Tags: python, python-2.7, wxpython, wxwidgets

default displayed on wxDatepickerctrl is mm-dd-YYYY (%m-%d-%Y).
How can I change format date displayed on wxDatepickerctrl on wxPython to dd/mm/YYYY (%d/%m/%Y) ?

Comment: which locale you program is using? EN_us?

Comment: is that any way to change format without change OS system date setting ?

Comment: you are not going to change that. wxWidgets (and wxPython) uses currently selected locasle in OS to detect date/time formatting. Though you can probably format it yourself by using wx.String.Format. Don't know if python has something similar.

Comment: The short answer appears to be No. See http://wxpython-users.1045709.n5.nabble.com/Set-dd-mm-yyyy-format-to-wx-DatePickerCtrl-td2363236.html